# Why does Rect(10,10,20,20) NOT intersect with Rect(20,20,30,30)

Tags: java, android

```
import android.graphics.Rect;

Rect r1 = Rect(10,10,20,20);
Rect r2 = Rect(20,20,30,30);


Rect.intersects(r1, r2); //returns FALSE
```

Why?

In my world the rectangles should intersect at 20,20

Comment: These are two rectangular regions bounded by these sides. So think of the edges as strictly less-than/greater-than, not equal to.

Comment: Does this compile? Shouldn't it be `Rect r1 = new Rect(10, 10, 20, 20)` ?

Comment: @Kon It's just an example. Look at where the `import` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Rect.intersects(r1,r2)` does following,

```
public static boolean intersects(Rect a, Rect b) {
    return a.left < b.right && b.left < a.right 
           && a.top < b.bottom && b.top < a.bottom;
 }
```

As @clark described in comment, - think of the edges as strictly less-than/greater-than, not equal to

Answer (score 0):

These coordinates are the borders of the rectangle. Two rectangles intersect with one another if at least one pixel is on both rectangles excluding their borders.

Answer (score 0):

To add @Jabbar Jigariyo

[image]

That's doesn't intersect actually...

P.S. Sorry for GnomePaint :(

And if you want to intersect in `20,20` make a method :

```
public static boolean intersects(Rect a, Rect b) {
    return a.left <= b.right && b.left <= a.right 
           && a.top <= b.bottom && b.top <= a.bottom;
 }
```